# How to programmatically invoke the error function in $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below, is it possible to call the error function from the else block?

```
$.getJSON('something.php', function(data) {
    if (data.error === undefined) {
    } else {
        // How can I call the error function below?
    }
}).error(function() {
    // This is the error function the be called.
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just define it separately and call it:

```
$.getJSON('something.php', function(data) {
    if (data.error === undefined) {
    } else {
        // How can I call the error function below?
        handleError();
    }
}).error(handleError);

function handleError() {
}
```

Comment: Haha you were a second quicker than me. I was writing the same thing.